# Solve captchas on an external webpage while using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, recaptcha, puppeteer

I'm attempting to write a program that checks out items on an e-commerce website that has a captcha. I plan on using Puppeteer to handle the checkout process and my question is how can I export the captchas found on the e-commerce site into another webpage for me to solve them as they become available?

Ideally, the program would handle the item selection, add to cart, and form filling on its own, then it would detect a captcha, send it to the external webpage, I solve it, and then the program can take the token and proceed with the checkout.

Comment: 1. The whole idea of a CAPTCHA is that only users, not bots would interact with the page protected by it. Still there are plenty resoucres on the topic to be found in Google. 2. Please create a question when you run into any specific trouble creating your script.

Comment: @Andrei Georgescu did you figure this out? There is this tool https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/captcha-solver, but I'm having issues integrating it.

Comment: Hey just saw this comment and I'm no longer working on this project, but this was exactly what I needed. I knew it was possible, thanks for sending it, gonna star it for the future!